# JavasScript Regex to exclude specific characters which are stored in a string variable, spaces, and change remaining characters to underscores

Tags: javascript

This is for a hangman-type guessing game.  I already figured out how to use a Regex to display the letters as underscores on the page with appropriate spacing.  Now I want use a Regex to do the following, all in one expression:

1. Check a string containing the correct answer `this.answers[arraysIndex]`, against the string containing all of the user's correct guesses `rightString`
2. In the correct answer string: change only the letters that don't match the correct guesses string into underscores. This means I want to keep the spaces unchanged too.

I've tried this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/(?![^"+rightString+"])/[\A-Za-z/])/","g");

newDisplay = (this.answers[arraysIndex]).replace(regex, "_");
```

...and this:

```
newDisplay = (this.answers[arraysIndex]).replace("/(?![^+rightString+])/[\A-Za-z/])/g", "_")
```

...and countless slight variations of each.  I'm not married to the idea of using a string variable, I could use an array variable too, or maybe there's something that hasn't even occurred to me.  I've researched exhaustively on here and many other resources (that's how I solved my first problem) but this one's got me beat.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use strings, and their corresponding UTF-16 code ex. [`"ABCD".charCodeAt(2) = 67` which is C](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) or [`charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) or [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm not clear on how to implement this to achieve what I want, though. Could anyone please provide some context? There are tons of situations on this site and others which have varying degrees of similarity to my objective, but I haven't found anything quite like it. So, everything I try involves cobbling together a hodgepodge of fundamentally different solutions. I'm still young in this field so I apologize. I'm not yet as strong as I'd like to be in that department.